# Property of Holder functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathcal{C}^\beta$ Holder function, $\beta\ge0$. Then by definition
$$
|f(x+z)-f(x)|\le C |z|^{\beta\wedge1},\quad x,z\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Can we generalize this statement in the following way: given $\gamma_1+\gamma_2\le \beta$ one has
$$
|f(x+y+z)-f(x+y)-f(x+z)-f(x)|\le C |y|^{\gamma_1\wedge1}|z|^{\gamma_2\wedge1},\quad x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Why not?...................

Comment: @daw so how to do it? is there a reference to a book  maybe (that would be ideal)?